# spark on yarn not release resource memory (Cloudera Manager)

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, cloudera, executor

When I run a spark job using hue in cloudera manager it executes successfully but it does not release resource from yarn manager. How to resolve this problem **SPARK ON HIVE CLOUDERA MANAGER**

Here is a screenshot of running jobs :[multiple job are holding the resources while they were executed successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/510M6.png)

Comment: You're wrong. Your job has been submitted only. It has not been finished yet. So how do you expect from the Resource Manager to release the resources without completing the job?

Comment: Job is completed successfully. i can attach job completion screenshot as well. and Here the details of job that display job status.
Name: Hive on Spark
Application Type: SPARK
Application Tags: 
State: FINISHED
FinalStatus: SUCCEEDED
Started: Tue Jun 12 19:29:28 +0530 2018
Elapsed: 12hrs, 15mins, 4sec

Comment: Job completed within 2 min but release resources after a long time(12 hrs).